# Implementing facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Trying to figure out which is best way to include `Login with Facebook` in my website.
Currently I am using a `png` image, onclick calls a php controller. This controller has access to Facebook PHP SDK. Controller talks to facebook api and authenticates the user.
But on web I have checked other way of implementations.
 First part is types of `facebook Login Button`:

- button developed with CSS only
- button developed XFBML
- just a login image

Second part is login implementation:

- Server side authentication (The way I am doing right now)
- Client side authentication. Using JS SDK and then passing session to PHP SDK
- make a call to facebook api via url and then redirecting to php code. something like `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appId&amp;scope=email&amp;redirect_uri=http//localhost/authenticate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook offers several login flows for different devices and projects.

**Client-side JavaScript SDK**

Difficulty: Low
Recommended for: Websites, Apps on Facebook and Mobile Apps

**Native Device Login**

Difficulty: Medium
Recommended for: Native Apps on supported Mobile Devices

**Server-side Login**

Difficulty: High
Recommended for: Desktop Apps or other environments where JavaScript isn't suitable

The above details are from Facebook developers website. P[lease check out this link for more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/).

Facebook suggesting to use Javascript SDK for websites because using FB.Login() just triggers a popup  window and gets response easily.  In certain cases, it may not be appropriate to use JavaScript or you may prefer to create a login flow in a different programming language then use Server-side login.